# Is there any way to create or declare arrays automatically?

Tags: c#

The arrays depending on the user input.
for example:

```
int n;//from the user
  for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
  {
   int[] arr + i = new int[5];
 }
```

that means create 4 arrays (n=4):

```
array1
array2
array3
array4
```

how can I create? Is there any method?

Comment: 2-dimensional array? `int[,] arr = new int[n, 5];` Then you'd access it like `int foo = arr[0, 1];`

Comment: yes. but how can I create unknown arrays? may be 10 or others depending on the user input.

Comment: Just like I showed; use the `n` that you got from the user. If `n` is 4, it'll create a 4 x 5 array. If `n` is 10, it'll create a 10 x 5 array, etc.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: Just to know   about how can I create many arrays automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what exactly you are trying to do. For your example, you could try using a list of arrays. Whenever you need a new array, add a new array to the list.

```
List<int[]> arrays = new List<int[]>();
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    arrays.Add(new int[5]);
}
```

To access a specific array in the list you can do

```
arrays[42]
```

To do something with all of the arrays, you can use a foreach loop:

```
foreach(var array in arrays) {
    array[0] += 42;
}
```